# How to get price html in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to display price in my custom template

```
   $productCollections = $productCollections->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('is_sale', 1)
                     // ->addAttributeToFilter('show_in_home', 1)
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                      ->load()
foreach($productCollections as $productCollection){
  echo $productCollection->getName();
}
```

I am using above code to implement product listing in home page.

I need to display price of product with html style

```
$this->getPriceHtml($product);
```

Answer (score 8):

For phtml use this :

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

For block just inject `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` into your block

Comment: You can get both simple and configurable product collection then how do u get price for config product which is shown in list page

Comment: Is this GetPtoductPrice () can differentiate itself which product is coming from collection to get price?

Comment: @RonakChauhan It's not working after I inject this block in my block. Can you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Here my question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246245/51810

Answer (score 3):

Block do not longer have method `getPriceHtml`.
You have to pass by another block to render a price, [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/behavior/pricing.html) the doc.

As you can see you have to make the following call into your block or template:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default')->render(
    '<price type>',
    $product,
    $arguments
);
```

The `price code` will be one of those: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/behavior/pricing.html#m2devgde-pricelib-def.

`base_price` is pretty good in general. :)

Hope this help.

Comment: `final_price` is used in the catalog_category_list by default.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This Code**

**Block File**

```
protected $resultLayout;
protected $_productloader;

public function __construct(
    ..............................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout,
    ..............................
) {
    ..............................
    $this->resultLayout = $resultLayout;
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    ..............................
}

..............................

public function getProductPriceHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
    $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class);
    if (!$priceRender) {
        $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
        );
    }
    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}

public function getProductData($id)
{
    return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
}
```

**phtml File**

```
$productid = 1088;

$product = $block->getProductData($productid);

echo $block->getProductPriceHtml($product);
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***