# Specific product price render in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, render

I want to render specific product price render in my custom page in block file.

I get reference from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/229036/51810) . But, It returns error :

```
main.CRITICAL: Wrong Price Rendering layout configuration. Factory block is missed [] []
```

How to render price box ?

Please help me.

Block File :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Helloworld\Block;

class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $_product;
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
    ) {
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getPrice($productID) {
        $product = $this->_product->load($productID);
        $price = '';
        $arguments = [];
        $priceType = \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE;
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render', 'product.price.render.default');
        $arguments['zone'] = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST;
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render($priceType, $product, $arguments);
        }
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Controller File :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $_customBlock;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld $customBlock
    ) {
        $this->_customBlock = $customBlock;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        return $this->_customBlock->getPrice(1);
    }
}
```

layout xml : (helloworld_index_index.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <referenceContainer name="content">
   <block class="Vendor\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld" name="formbuilder" template="Vendor_Helloworld::helloworld.phtml"/>
  </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

I take reference from this both answer :

1) [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186735/51810)
2) [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/229036/51810)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share some code

Comment: Please check it @AmitBera.

Comment: I added this code in my block file. I call one controller using ajax. And this block function call in controller. But, it return system.log. If I add this in one file which is display on page load then it will display pricebox.

Comment: You have to load  render layout

Comment: okay. can you please tell me how ? I mean which layout should i render?

Comment: Can you please update your answer?

Comment: You are great @AmitBera :) !! It's working. I need to load render layout for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For render price template in the specific block,
you need to call function like below,

```
public function getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
    if (!$priceRender) {
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            'product.price.render.default',
            ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
        );
    }

    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'display_minimal_price'  => true,
                'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir @RakeshJesadiya. I got solution by Amit Bera's hint about render layout. I find that way and get result. But, your answer is better :)

Comment: You can check core code from  module-catalog/Block/Rss/Product/NewProducts.php to render price.

Comment: Oh...!! Yes. I didn't see in that file. I just look over on swatches and ListProduct.php file. Thanks for guiding me :)

Comment: Great. It worked

Comment: Great. It is working.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try below solution:**

```
   $arguments = [];
$priceType = \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE;
$priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
$arguments['zone'] = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST;
$price = ''
if ($priceRender) {
    $price = $priceRender->render($priceType, $product, $arguments);
}

echo $price;
```

If layout still not render, then you need to inject `\Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface` in your construct :

```
   /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    protected $_view;

    public function __construct(
        ..........
        \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view,
        ..........
    ) {
        ..........
        $this->_view = $view;
        ..........
    }
```

And need to inject `Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory` in your controller

```
   /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        ..........
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ..........      
    ) {
        ..........
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        ..........
    }
    public function execute() {
          ........
          $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
          ........
    }
```

Then, you can use this below line for successfully price render layout.

```
$priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
```

Comment: Same system.log return.

Comment: I use like this : $this->_layout->getBlock('product.price.render.default');

Comment: construct : \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,

Comment: You have tried at block then you have to change `$block->getLayout()`  to `$this->getLayout()`

Comment: It returns blank. I think block not render. So, It's not enter in if condition.

Comment: I added block,controller and layout xml file.

Comment: Is there any solution for that ? Or any bug in my code? It's most imp for me if this question solve.

Comment: Thank you sir :) I just edit your answer for render layout.

Comment: i got error in magento 2.3.2 Uncaught Error: Call to a member function renderAmount() on boolean in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/AbstractOptions.php:166

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $resultLayout;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout
) {
    $this->resultLayout = $resultLayout;
}

public function getProductPriceHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
    $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class);
    if (!$priceRender) {
        $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
        );
    }
    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***